# Why Slather report counted comments in functions

Tags: swift, code-coverage, slather

As the image bellow shows, looks like the comment in the function have been counted as code.

[image]

Comment: You are probably better off posting a question to the [Slather github page](https://github.com/SlatherOrg/slather). Quoting: _"You can also [submit a new GitHub issue](https://github.com/SlatherOrg/slather/issues/new) if you find bugs or have questions. "_.

Comment: @dfri  Thank you, I'll do that.

Comment: Recorded in https://github.com/SlatherOrg/slather/issues/332, so looks like I should close it here?

Comment: You are free to answer your own question here at SO with a link recording your Github question to Slather:s official page, as well as the response from the devs working on Slather. But you might want to wait until you get an answer at Github to post an answer here.

Comment: (... based on your image it looks as if Slather uses, for the version you're using anyway, a quite naive line count for line coverage, which doesn't remove blankspaces, comments of even finalizing body braces).